# Censor words with the same number of stars than the word length

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all words of 1 or 2 characters by stars.
I currently use this rule:

```
$validTxt = preg_replace("/\\b\\w{1,2}\\b/", '*', $validTxt);
```

But when the word have 2 characters, it is replaced by only 1 star, not 2.
I need a FAST way of doing this. The performance is the priority, even if it require 100 lines of code.

Comment: Please use _single quoted strings_ for regex patterns. All those (unnecessary) backslashes hurt my eyes! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect time to pull out the `'e'` modifier which allows you to put executable code in the replacement string. (Note that this `'e'` modifier may only be used with `preg_replace()`) This tested function does the trick:

```php
function words_to_stars($text) {
    $replace = 'str_repeat("*", strlen("$0"));';
    return preg_replace('/\b\w{1,2}\b/e', $replace, $text);
}
```

Note that this method will not be as fast as nikic's callback solution, but I thought I'd throw this answer into the ring anyhoo ('cause many probably don't know about this handy feature.)

**Update: Benchmarks, oh my!**
I was curious about which method would be fastest, and by how much, so I just measured the speeds of the various methods using a handy benchmark function I have floating around. I took each of the three methods and created a function to cleanly implement each one. (Note that I had to modify Nikic's solution because my PHP 5.2.14 did not like the syntax placing the function directly into the `preg_replace_callback()` parameter.) Here are the functions that were measured:

```
// Ridgerunner's "e_modifier" method:
function words_to_stars_e_modifier($validTxt) {
    return preg_replace('/\b\w{1,2}\b/e',
        'str_repeat("*", strlen("$0"));',
        $validTxt);
}

// nikic's "callback" method (modified):
function words_to_stars_callback($validTxt) {
    return preg_replace_callback('~\b\w{1,2}\b~',
        '_words_to_stars_callback',
        $validTxt);
}
function _words_to_stars_callback($matches) {
    return str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[0]));
}

// Eva611, Matt and anubhava's "array" method:
function words_to_stars_array($validTxt) {
    return preg_replace(
        array('/\b\w{1}\b/', '/\b\w{2}\b/'),
        array('*',            '**'),
        $validTxt);
}
```

I took the text from this very webpage as the test data and then measured how long each function took to do its thing (on my AMD64 3700+ Win32 XP box). Here are the results of the benchmarks tests: (Drumroll, please!)

```
e_modifier() Nreps: 133  Time: 1.050 s  Function time: 0.007893 sec
callback()   Nreps: 213  Time: 1.034 s  Function time: 0.004856 sec
array()      Nreps: 578  Time: 1.016 s  Function time: 0.001758 sec
```

As I suspected, the `'e'` modifier method was slowest. The callback method came in second, and Eva611, Matt and anubhava's array method wins by a landslide!

Answer (score 3):

```
$validTxt = preg_replace_callback(
    '~\b\w{1,2}\b~',
    function($matches) { return str_repeat('*', strlen($matches[0])); },
    $validTxt
);
```

The advantage of this is that you can change the limits `{1,2}`, without adjusting some regex => replacement array.

Comment: I'm curious as to the performance of this vs. the array approach (as that was a concern to the asker), but I like the use of a callback and the flexibility.  It does seem a little more elegant than filling several array items.

Comment: +1: Note that you can alternatively use the little known `'e'` modifier (see my answer), but this callback solution will be faster.

Comment: @ridgerunner: I do know about the `e` modifier, but I didn't want to use it, because it has a really negative connotation. People typically use the `e` modifier to hide evals in exploit code. You will often see code like `preg_replace('/./', base64_decode('Some encoded code'), 'x');` in hacking scripts. In this particular use case using `e` would be safe, but in many others it'll open a big security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Uhh, two passes is just my first thought:

```
$validTxt = preg_replace('/\b\w{1}\b/', '*', $validTxt);

$validTxt = preg_replace('/\b\w{2}\b/', '**', $validTxt);
```

But I'm rusty on regex and don't know if there is a better way.

EDIT: Since I see that you can pass an array, I'm expanding upon that solution:

```
$pattern = array();
$pattern[0] = '/(\b)\w{1}(\b)/';
$pattern[1] = '/(\b)\w{2}(\b)/';

$replace = array();
$replace[0] = '$\0*$\1';
$replace[1] = '$\0**$\1';

$validTxt = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $validTxt)
```

Okay, that **should** also keep the whitespace around the old text, which means the order doesn't matter.  But if you wanted to replace the whitespace, you'd need to modify the code.

Comment: There is no preg_replace_all function. preg_replace defaults to replacing everything unless you specify a limit with an optional parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I blindly copied that from another answer in forming my own.  Just fixed it before I saw your comment.  Whoops! Although, now I see that you can pass an array, which is slightly better than my solution

Comment: What's with the downvote?  Because of the incorrect function name, or is my solution actually that bad?

Comment: At the time, you were pushing a function which didn't exist. i've changed it to an Up now.

Comment: Gotcha, don't want people seeing a ton of references to it and thinking it is.

Comment: Actually you should reverse the 2 lines ( make the 2 char replacement before the 1 chr ).

Comment: @FMaz008 I think I see what you mean.  It is because the replace will eat the \b characters.  I think it may be more appropriate to keep those characters in the replaced text...

Answer (score 1):

Alright try this:

```
$p = array();
$p[0] = '/\b\w{1}\b/';
$p[1] = '/\b\w{2}\b/';

$r = array();
$r[0] = '*';
$r[1] = '**';

echo preg_replace($p, $r, "a") . "\n"; // prints *
echo preg_replace($p, $r, "ab") . "\n"; // prints **
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can pass arrays in preg_replace
$pattern = array();
$censor = array();
$pattern[0] = '/\b\w{1}\b/';
$pattern[1] = '/\b\w{2}\b/';
$censor[0] = '*';
$censor[1] = '**';

$validTxt = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $validTxt)
```

Answer (score -2):

Just a thought, but you might be able to use a match group, then do a strlen on it wrapped in a str_repeat:

```
$validTxt = preg_replace("/\\b(\\w{1,2})\\b/", str_repeat('*', str_len("$1")), $validTxt);
```

I don't have access to a PHP dev env at the moment, so this untested.

Comment: You'll want to use preg_replace_all to change all occurrences in the entire $validTxt string but AFAIK the pattern \\w{1,2} will only ever be replaced by one asterisk, so answers listing that as the solution are wrong.

Comment: There is no preg_replace_all - by default it'll replace everything unless you pass in an optional "limit" parameter.

Comment: You can't just put an expression into the replace parameter ;)

Comment: The terminology used, e.g. "Just a thought, but you **might** be able to" and "I don't have access to a PHP dev env at the moment, **so this is untested**" should elude to the fact I was offering suggestions for someone who is stumped and not proffering a concrete answer.  The comment regarding non-existent method preg_replace_all was meant to highlight the misunderstanding by some that {1,2} would cause 1 or 2 asterisks as replacements.  I will avoid offering any suggestions on stackoverflow as even when explicitly not phrased as solution peer review here is quite harsh